# Why doesn't analogWrite() work

Tags: arduino-uno, analogwrite

Can anybody tell me why these analogWrite() statements are being ignored. The code is entering the "if"statements because the Serial.println() statements are being executed.

```
    class Pwm
{
  unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
  unsigned long currentMillis;
  int LED;
  int DELAY;
  int up;
  int down;
  int x;

  public:
  Pwm(int led, int Delay) {

    int LED = led;
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

    DELAY = Delay;
    up = 1;
    down = 0;
    x = 0;

  }

  void Update() {
    currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= DELAY && up == 1) {
    analogWrite(LED, x);
    x++;
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    Serial.println(x);
    if (x == 256) {
      up = 0;
      down = 1;
    }
  }
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= DELAY && down == 1) {
    analogWrite(LED, x);
    x--;
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    Serial.println(x);
    if (x == 0) {
      up = 1;
      down = 0;
    }
   }
  }

};

// create Flasher Objects
Flasher red(12, 1000, 250);
//Flasher yellow(11, 500, 500);
//Flasher green(10, 250, 1000);
//Flasher blue(8, 250, 500);

// create PWM Objects
Pwm pin9(9,8);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  red.Update();
  //yellow.Update();
  //green.Update();
  //blue.Update();
  pin9.Update();
}
```

if I load this code everything works fine. I only have issues with the OOP method.

```
int LED = 9;
int DELAY = 8;
int up = 1;
int down = 0;
int x;
unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= DELAY && up == 1) {
    analogWrite(LED, x);
    x++;
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    if (x == 256) {
      up = 0;
      down = 1;
    }
  }
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= DELAY && down == 1) {
    analogWrite(LED, x);
    x--;
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    if (x == 0) {
      up = 1;
      down = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does pin 9 on you board support PWM?

Comment: Yes the second sketch works just fine and uses the same pin as the first

Comment: Ermm... yes...doh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor in your `Pwm` class declares a local variable `LED` which it sets equal to the parameter `led`. You use the member variable `LED` in other methods, so you probably meant to set the member variable of the same name, not create a local.

Remove the `int` from before `LED = led` in the constructor.

Comment: So by creating the local variable LED in the constructor the update() method doesnt see pin 9 being set to output? Please correct me if I'm wrong. I can't make changes to my sketch until later. I will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: @beewrangler Yes that's correct.  C++ lets you declare two variables with the same name at different 'scopes' (some compilers warn you).  Put simply scope is between the braces {}, you know of global variables and then function variables, they are two examples of scope.  You have define LED as a class member (class scope) and then LED as a function variable (function scope).  The lowest level of scope takes precedence, function level, and when you are outside the constructor, but inside the class (i.e. `update()`) then the class member is used.  Good spot Mark.

Comment: As stated above by Mark Smith I had my LED variable scope wrong. His suggestion has fixed my problem. Thank you